# How to include a file from a private GitHub repo?

Tags: php, github

Is it possible to include a php file, which exists in a private repo, in a file in a public repo?

For example,

config.php in public repo

```
$path = "path_to_github_private_repo";

include("$path/config.php");
```

Comment: If you've cloned it so you have it on your server, then sure. Once you've cloned it, it's just files in your system. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I think yes: it is possible. And you already wrote the code. I think also you are asking before trying something. It is possibile that you are loookng for a solution to include different public and private projects using composer?

Comment: The file in the private repo contains sensitive db info (php code). I want to include the code existing into it, without being visible, in the config file at my public repo.